# Next of paging is not working, in instagram API call

Tags: facebook, graph, comments, instagram

I am using the below given URL for GET request -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/INSTAGRAM_MEDIA_ID?fields=comments{text,timestamp,replies}&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

The data it returns contains a next cursor, which looks like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/INSTAGRAM_MEDIA_ID/comments?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN&pretty=1&fields=text\u00252Ctimestamp\u00252Creplies&limit=25&after=AFTER_TOKEN
```

When I do GET request on the above URL, It returns this error.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"\\\".\" at character 4: text\\u00252Ctimestamp\\u00252Creplies",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500,
      "fbtrace_id": "FB_TRACE_ID"
   }
}
```

If I do a normal request like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/INSTAGRAM_MEDIA_ID/comments?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It also returns data that contains next URL, which is working fine.

The post one which I am doing this request has more than 25 comments hence I need to use next URL here.

The normal request(non nested one) doesn't return replies on comments, but I need to see replies too, that's why I am doing a nested request.

Comment: I'd file a bug report, and ask Facebook to fix this: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Comment: As a workaround, until it is fixed, you should be able to extract the `AFTER_TOKEN` value from the URL the API is giving you, and then append that query string parameter to your original API request URL.

Comment: I have tried doing that, i.e. URL + &pretty=1&limit=25&after= + AFTER_TOKEN, but it is returning the same data